# How to use HP SCA to scan my iOS project and get a report

Tags: ios, macos, xcode6, fortify

> Windows:

I have HP SCA 4.21 installed on my Windows7 64 bit machine with license and rule-packs.

I have my iOS project downloaded on the same machine.

Then I did the following thing:

1. I opened the AuditWorkbench, there is only two options under the "Start New Project": "Scan Java Project" and "Advance Scan...". I choose the Advance scan.
2. I selected the root of the iOS project, the .h and .m files are not shown at all, the only files shown are the html files.
3. I continued to the end finding out that it scanned only those html files.

> Mac:

Then I installed SCA 4.21 on my Mac mini(OSX-10.10, Xcode-6.2, iOS-8.2) and downloaded the iOS project.

I followed the same steps and get the same result, it didn't recognize the .h and .m files either.

Then I used the sourceanalyze command in the terminal:

```
sourceanalyzer -b YYYY -clean
sourceanalyzer -b YYYY xcodebuild -project YYYY.xcodeproj -target YYYY -configuration Debug =sdk iphonesimulator8.2 ARCHS=i386 GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=NO OTHER_CFLAGS="-w"
```

then the xcodebuild compiled the project, but with a lot of generated errors, like:

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAccelerometer.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:74:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURL.h:86:1: error: 'objc_returns_inner_pointer' attribute only applies to methods
@property (readonly) __strong const char *fileSystemRepresentation NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
^                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
9 errors generated.
```

Then I entered the command:

```
sourceanalyzer -b buildID -scan -f buildID.fpr
```

which gave me something like this:

```
[warning]: NST file: /Users/xxx/.fortify/sca6.2/build/yyy/Users/xxx/Documents/workspace/YYYY/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m.nst does not exist or removed.
[warning]: Some errors or warnings were suppressed.  Check the results file for a full listing of all warnings and errors.
```

I opened the buildID.fpr, and the workbench told me:

- there was no issues found, not a single one.
- scanned 55 files, 0 LOC(Executable)
- 661 warnings occurred during scan

*My instinct told me a probable truth that something went wrong, and very wrong.*

*I just happened to be unknown of the problem here.*

*I have succeeded running Android project on my Windows machine.*

*It seems it doesn't support Object-C, but I doubt that.*

*Do I needs a special license that support the iOS object-c? I don't think so, but I am not sure.*

So, here comes the famous question:

> How to use HP SCA to scan my iOS project and get a report?

Anyone, any suggestions, any help?

Comment: Do the compiler errors occur without using sourceanalyzer? You'll also want to check the sca log file. 661 warnings tells me something isn't configured correctly. FYI, you may get quicker responses by posting this over at https://protect724.hp.com. That's the Fortify community.

Comment: hi @Eric, no compiler error occur without using sourceanalyzer (I simply removed the "sourceanalyzer -b YYYY").

Comment: @Eric, I checked the sca log file, and opened the .fpr file in workbench, the 661 warnings are like "NST file main.m.nst not exist or removed" and a lot of "NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER" problem. I don't know about the NST files, but I guess they're the intermediate file that should've been created by sca to build the model. And I know that the translation stage goes wrong because the output has the line:Translation errors occurred during execution of /....../clang.fortify.  Probably it's because sth isn't configured correctly, like you said.

Comment: The Fortify community you told me helped, but it didn't work out. I need to post this over there. Thanks for telling me this.

Comment: No problem. I'm sure you'll find some help over there. I would also take a look at the file permissions. Lots of missing NST files may be an issue with writing to the temp directories for Fortify.

Comment: Hi @user3151209, did you solve this problem? I also got NST file xxxx does not exist or removed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Scott, for a quick answer, I post the key words: there's an experimental hotfix available which should allow you to at least get some results with v4.21 - to obtain this please drop an email to our support team at fortifytechsupport@hp.com. They'll be able to assist you further.

Comment: @Scott, for more information, u can open "protect724.hp.com", search "SCA ios", there r some post there. I would recommend the one created by leo, because that's me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem by applying a hotfix. But I think they can support it now with the newest release.

On the Mac, However SCA 4.21 does not support Xcode 6.2, as such we're not actually scanning any of the source. Support for Xcode 6.2 will released as part of v4.30 which I didn't try.

There's an experimental hotfix available which should allow us to at least get some results with v4.21 - to obtain this please drop an email to the support team at [fortifytechsupport@hp.com](http://fortifytechsupport@hp.com). They'll be able to assist further.

Or, search/posting this over at [protect724.hp.com](http://protect724.hp.com). That's the Fortify community.
Gratitude to @Eric